# Bring energy into mixing hot and cold taps

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, flow

Are you able to bring energy into your equation?

I like to know if there is a way to calculate the required energy necessary to obtain a given temperature and flow at the outlet of the mixer when hot and cold flow and temperature are known.

Answer (score 0):

If $\dot{m}_H$ and $\dot{m}_C$ are the mass flow rates of hot water and cold water delivered to the tap, the temperature of the water coming out of the tap is:
$$T=\frac{\dot{m}_HT_H+\dot{m}_CT_C}{\dot{m}_H+\dot{m}_C}$$And the rate of heat flow from the hot water to the cold water is $$\dot{Q}=\dot{m}_HC(T_H-T)=\dot{m}_CC(T-T_C)$$where C is the specific heat capacity of water.

Comment: Great thanks! Is Q expressed in Joule?